# Pointing pip3 to python3.5 instead of python3.6

Tags: pip, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6, python-3.5

I just recently installed pip (3.6) by building it with python3.6 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.6 get-pip.py
```

This completed successfully but changed the pip3 binary under `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to correspond to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)` instead of `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)`

I have tried,

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/pip3 pip3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip 1`

to make `sudo update-alternatives --config pip3` work and finally point to python3.5 dist-packages.

The error that i am getting,

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip because link group pip3 is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/local/bin/pip3 with a link
```

Please advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing pip3 to python3.5 instead of python3.6

```
python3.5 $(which pip3) install <your-package-name>
```